# $\sum C_n6^n$ converges $\implies \sum C_n(-6)^n$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\sum C_n6^n$ converges $\implies \sum C_n(-6)^n$ converges

Is this true?
It is true when $\forall n\space C_n>0$ by absolute convergence test but I have no idea when $\forall n\space C_n>0$ is not true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$C_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{6^n n}$$.